# Why does AS wants compile project after flutter update

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter, android-gradle-plugin

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Just updated flutter to 1.5.4-hotfix.2
and now my project doesnt compile but my co-worker had no problems with same version

CONSOLE OUTPUT

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM G955F in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  Output:  D:\Desktop\asdPrj\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
  D:\Desktop\asdPrj\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
  D:\Desktop\asdPrj\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:906: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  D:\Desktop\asdPrj\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:906: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  error: failed linking references.

  Command: C:\Users\Janer\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\78f68b33382372bc3dc84b96fd530582\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          C:\Users\Janer\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          D:\Desktop\asdPrj\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          D:\Desktop\asdPrj\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
          -R\
          @D:\Desktop\asdPrj\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          D:\Desktop\asdPrj\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
          --custom-package\
          ga.aninet\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          D:\Desktop\asdPrj\build\app\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
  Output:  C:\Users\Janer\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-1.0.0.aar\9a8530dc700588f390ca440a65237576\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

  D:\Desktop\asdPrj\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

  C:\Users\Janer\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-1.0.0.aar\becf871373d3300ffd53f5291be852df\res\values\values.xml:89:5-125:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

  C:\Users\Janer\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-1.0.0.aar\becf871373d3300ffd53f5291be852df\res\values\values.xml:89:5-125:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

  error: failed linking references.
  Command: C:\Users\Janer\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\78f68b33382372bc3dc84b96fd530582\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          C:\Users\Janer\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          D:\Desktop\asdPrj\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          D:\Desktop\asdPrj\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
          -R\
          @D:\Desktop\asdPrj\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          D:\Desktop\asdPrj\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
          --custom-package\
          ga.aninet\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          D:\Desktop\asdPrj\build\app\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at [gradle url](https://help.gradle.org)

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

---

The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
See [googleHref][2] for more information on the problem and how to fix it.

---

Answer (score 0):

Execute the `flutter clean` command in your project, to erase everything in cache of previous compilations

Comment: Clean this directory ** C:\Users\Janer\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\ ** , so that you can download it again